# Convert value into unsigned 32 bit

Tags: python, bash, shell, awk

I need to know the equivalent bash statement of the below Python statement.

```
xa = ctypes.c_uint32(a).value
```

I think this variable `a` converts into 32bit unsigned integer.

Basically I need to convert integer value (positive or negative) into 32bit unsigned value in bash.

when i type following command in python shell, it gives me the same value.

`ctypes.c_uint32(4029987).value`

output is

`4029987`

when i type following command in python shell, it gives me the below value.

`ctypes.c_uint32(-4029987).value`

output is

`4294544309`

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: i need to do same thing in bash also....

Comment: You used twice `ctypes.c_uint32(4029987).value` with different results?

Comment: I cannot replicate, you also say *when i type following command in python shell* twice so not really sure what you are asking

Comment: sorry.. 2nd one should be minus value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert unsigned integers into binary, you can use `bc`.

Basic decimal to binary conversion can be done like this

```
$ echo "obase=2;42" | bc
101010
```

To handle negativ and positiv input number, just add `| sed 's/^-//'` which will suppress potential minus sign from the output

Finally, if you really want to print 32-bit binary numbers I suggest you use `printf` like this :

```
$ printf '%032d' $(echo "obase=2; -42" | bc | sed 's/^-//')
00000000000000000000000000101010
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing with `xa = ctypes.c_uint32(a).value` in python is asigning the **decimal** value of `a` to `xa` **assuming** that `a` is an unsigned integer of 32 bits. Simply called a long in many instances (but not always).

However, when you write `ctypes.c_uint32(4029987).value` you are already using the **decimal** value of the 4 bytes (the long). That is why you get again the decimal value of 4029987.

The problem with bash (for this issue) is that bash does not have a similar concept of types. All values in shell are both string and decimal, at the same time. Values are converted as needed.

So, in bash, a variable that contains the decimal value of 4029987 could be assigned as (note that there are no spaces):

```
a=4029987
```

What do you want to do with it?

Know the hex value?

```
$ printf '%08x' "$a"
003d7e23
```

Print the hex representation of the negative of that value?

```
$  printf '%08x' "-$a"
ffffffffffc281dd
```

That's 64 bits (as I am working in a 64 bits system). See how the shell use the representation that is needed. From the text string `-4029987` to the 64 bit representation of such decimal number.

Of course, you could cut the value to a 32 bit value:

```
$ xa=$(printf '%08x' "-$a")
$ xa=${xa%????????}
$ echo $xa
ffc281dd
```

And, that string of hexadecimal numbers (ffc281dd) back in decimal:

```
$ echo $((16#$xa))
4290937309
```

Which happens to coincide with what you got in Python. But, again, that does not work in the same way in shell.

Comment: `xa=$(printf '%08x' "-$a")` yields `bash: printf: --4029987: invalid number` for `a=-4029987`.

Comment: `xa=${xa%????????}` yields `ffffffff` for previous xa=ffffffffffc281dd.

Answer (score 1):

the thing here is that ctypes work with [Signed number in two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Two.27s_complement), that means that every negative number have its firsts bit in 1 among other things

that is why

```
>>> ctypes.c_uint32(-4029987).value
4294544309  # 11111111110000101000000111011101 <-- -4029987
            # 00000000001111010111111000100011 <--  4029987
```

or

```
>>> ctypes.c_uint32(-1).value
4294967295  # 11111111111111111111111111111111 <-- -1
            # 00000000000000000000000000000001 <--  1
```

internally it do something equivalent to

```
number&0xffffffff
```

if you want to keep the same magnitude regardless of sign do

```
ctypes.c_uint32(abs(number))
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in the same sense as user2350426's approach, with the advantage that it really works:

```
a=-4029987
xa=$(printf %d 0x`printf %x $a | sed 's/.*\(.\{8\}\)/\1/'`)
```

By the way, the correct output for this example value is `4290937309`, not `4294544309` as stated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent bash statement for the below Python statement :

```
xa = ctypes.c_uint32(a).value
```

> Bash variables are untyped.Unlike many other programming languages,
>   Bash does not segregate its variables by "type."

When `type` itself is not present, you can't even imagine `unsigned type`.

**Reference:**

[TLDP Article on Bash Variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/untyped.html)

Comment: I am not the one who downvoted you. someone else downvoted. i am new bee

Comment: @etutionlanka : That is understood pal ! :) Anyway I am hoping to get the reason for the downvote because i'm afraid if I have a misconception